# how to get crystal report with same data in multiple page with different heading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2005, crystal-reports-2008

i m new to crystal report and currently i am designing an Invoice with Crystal report 8. It needs 3 copies on every print. All copies show the same things but the only difference is a wording - Original, Office Copy & Customer Copy respectively. How can dis be achieved.
any advice will be much appreciated.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to add another table to the report via `Crystal Reports -> Database -> Database Expert` called  "CopyName" that has three records in it "Original", "Office Copy" and "Customer Copy".

Then, in the "links" tab of the database expert, if you don't specify the relationship, that will mean that the resulting dataset that your report is based on will have three times as many records as before, one for each record in "CopyName".

Then, add a new group via `Crystal Reports -> Reports -> Group Expert` for the new field you have added.  Depending upon whether or not you want your report grouped on Customer and then "Copy Name" or "Copy Name" then Customer, you can move this new field up and down in the "Group By" part of the Group Expert".

Lastly, you will be able to add the new field to the page header so you can tell if the page is the original, the office copy or the customer copy.